# Hazelcast server as a linux service

Tags: hazelcast

How to run hazelcast server as a linux service in production environments ?

java -server -cp hazelcast.jar com.hazelcast.examples.StartServer

StartServer runs the server with outputs to std terminal, what's the easiest way to run it as a linux service and write logs to a file
& how do I specify min and max memory allocation for Hazelcast.

I have to set it up as a service in an EC2 instance and bundle it. When EC2 autoscaling starts an instance, hazelcast server will start and join the cluster.

Thanks

Comment: Hazelcast normally is not run as a standalone environment, but embedded within a JVM. 

How are you using Hazelcast? Can you tell a bit more about it?

Comment: I currently have a runnable jar with a hazelcast.xml in the path. The xml file contains configuration details for Ec2 auto discovery option enabled. When the EC2 instance is started I run the  "nohup java -cp hazelcast.jar com.hazelcast.StartServer >> /opt/hazelcast.log" command to start the server. Please point me  references to embed hazelcast with a jvm. - Thanks

Comment: To be honest, there currently is no such functionality available for Hazelcast. It would not be that complicated to add I think. 

My suggestion would be to look at e.g. Tomcat or Jetty which scripts are needed to setup it up a service. It also varies a lot from distribution to distribution btw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use Hazelcast as a service you just need to write a shell/bash script that starts and stops the java application. Then for controlling your Hazelcast configuration you need to pass in the system property `hazelcast.config` with the path to the file which contains the hazelcast.xml configuration.

Moreover, if you want to have custom logging you can include the JAR files (for log4j2, for example) and set the system property `log4j.configurationFile` and the path to the XML/JSON file with the logging configuration. Do not forget to set the property `hazelcast.logging.type` to the according type in your hazelcast config.

As an example code, here you have a really simple bash script for doing what you want. I have not tested it and it is just something to guide you:

```
#!/bin/bash

function start {
   cd /opt/hazelcast
   rm -f /opt/hazelcast/hazelcast.pid
   javaCmd = "/my/java/home/bin/java -server -cp hazelcast.jar:apache-log4j-2.0-beta9.jar -Dhazelcast.config=/opt/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/hazelcast/log4j2.xml com.hazelcast.examples.StartServer"
   cmd="nohup $javaCmd >> /opt/hazelcast/service.log 2>&1 & echo \$! >/opt/hazelcast/hazelcast.pid"
   su -c "$cmd"
   return 0; }


function stop {
   pid="$(</opt/hazelcast/hazelcast.pid)"
   kill -s KILL $pid || return 1
   return 0; }


function main {
   RETVAL=0
   case "$1" in
      start)                                               
         start
         ;;
      stop)                                                
         stop
         ;;
      *)
         echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
         exit 1
         ;;
      esac
   exit $RETVAL
}


main $1
```