# Application Scaling with HazelCast IMDG Open Source

Tags: amazon-ec2, hazelcast

I have a java application running on a single Instance EC2 server. I want to implement autoscaling in the server, but my java application will not work on active-active mode.

So, I have started looking at Hazelcast IMDG open source for Application Scaling Purpose.

I am new to Hazelcast. So, Can anyone give me the idea about How can I implement Hazelcast open source for my Application Scaling and what will be the steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a Hazelcast cluster on EC2 with Auto Scaling turned on. See here for details: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws/blob/master/README.md

Comment: You can also check the related Blog Post: https://hazelcast.com/blog/aws-auto-scaling-with-hazelcast

Comment: @Rafal Leszko, this blog is related to implementing autoscaling after installation of hazelcast. I have not installed hazelcast in my server yet. I need to know how can i install and use hazelcast open source.

Comment: So to start Hazelcast you simply download it and start the `start.sh` script, like described here: https://blog.petehouston.com/start-hazelcast-standalone-server/. Or you can read how to set up Hazelcast as Linux Service here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019450/hazelcast-server-as-a-linux-service